# Python - Fastest way to update multiple records in one table by selecting id from B table

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7

I have two tables in MySQL, which named A and B.

- A table scheme : a_id, u_id
- B table schema : b_id, u_id

I want to update B table u_id by selecting A table's u_id, with the condition a_id is equal to b_id.

For example, record in A looks like ('001', 'a00'),('003', 'a01'); 
record in B looks like ('001', ''), ('002', ''), ('003', '')

I want to update B table records with the result ('001', 'a00'), ('003', 'a01')

What is the fastest way to update the B table's u_id value? 
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
UPDATE tableB SET column2 = tableA.column2 WHERE tableB.column1 = tableA.column1
```

you can read up more on up update sql [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

Please let me know if you have any questions!